# How does SO calculates number of votes, answers and views in database?

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, join, count

I think SO and other question/answer systems are perfect example for advanced TSQL techniques. I am wondering how SO and other questions/answers systems work with DB tables. I am particulary interested what is the TSQL select for list of questions where you also want to show number of votes and answers.

Table `question` would be specified as this

```
id       int 
title    varchar
id_user  int
```

table `votes` so you can monitor users votes for particular question

```
id_user       int
id_question   int
vote          int
```

table 'answer' with replies to question

```
id           int
id_parent    int
```

What would select look like to get result from `question` like this:

```
id                 int
title              varchar
votes_count        int
answers_count      int
```

I was thinking about two methods

1. Table `question` would recalculate with every vote or answer and update table fields `votes_count` and `answers_count` directly in `question` table. That means table `question` would have also `votes_count int, answers_count int`
2. Create select which would join, calculate `count` directly in `votes` or `answers` tables and just show results in `question` table. How much speed would be lost by counting with every select all the records for votes and answers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I **guess** that SO just uses 3 tables for this - questions, votes and answers, and joins them without doing any kind of caching (no answer_cnt / vote_cnt columns in the questions table).

The performance penalty should be nothing to worry about - after all, SO has "just" about 3.4 mio questions (according to the SO start page), which really isn't much data for a modern RDBMS.